# canvas toDataUrl upload to gae

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

I convert a canvas to data url and post it to GAE.  The post works on localhost but returns a 400 when deployed.  There's no error in the log, and it seems that the request doesn't even make it to my upload handler.

here's the jquery code that does the post

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function() {
        stage.toDataURL({
            callback: function(dataUrl) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ upload_url|safe }}",
                    data: {file: dataUrl}
                }).done(function( respond ) {
                    alert(respond);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Here's the python code that handle the post

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
      logging.info('uploading image')
      self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"

```
  try:
      data = self.request.get('file')
      data_to_64 = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', data).group(1)
      decoded = data_to_64.decode('base64')

      logging.info('Create the file')
      file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='image/png')

      logging.info('Open the file and write to it')
      with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write(decoded)

      logging.info('Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.')
      files.finalize(file_name)

      key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)

      url = '/serve/%s' % key
      self.response.out.write('{ "url": "' + url + '" }')
  except Exception, e:
      logging.error(e)
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was only looking at the 400 not the response body.  The body said the endpoint did not support the content type i was sending.

if you go through this tutorial https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

you create an upload url using blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')

the endpoint created only supports the content type mulitpart/form-data

the was i was sending the data using jquery has the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

So my fix was not use blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload'), just post directly to /upload